# Trying to create a button in Xcode Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, button, audio

I am just trying something completely new and simple in Xcode. I was looking a tutorial to create a button that plays music or a sound. All seemed to be okay until preview time. There seems to be an expected identifier issue at IBAction as well as it expected something after (void). But each time I do as the prompt says the prompts multiply. I've tried to do as all of them said but then it was no longer the same function. Any ideas?

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <AudioToolbox/AudioToolbox.h>

@interface StrackerViewController : ViewController

//@end

//@implementation StrackerViewController: ViewController

- (IBAction) epic; {

    CFBundleRef mainBundle = CFBundleGetMainBundle();
    CFURLRef soundFileURLRef;
    soundFileURLRef = CFBundleCopyResourceURL(mainBundle, (CFStringRef) @ "epic", CFSTR ("mp3"),NULL);
    UInt32 soundID;
    AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID(soundFileURLRef, &soundID);
    AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(soundID);
                    }

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

Comment: Why are you using CoreFoundation?

Comment: Is that the .h or the .m?

Comment: Sorry, it is Viewcontroller.m

Comment: And Core Foundation is what was recommended in the tutorial I was using

Comment: Uncomment `//@end
//@implementation StrackerViewController: ViewController`

Comment: Thanks everyone, I have no more errors on this page now.( It was definitely the commented parts)

Answer (score 0):

Your IBAction is not a properly formed function. It needs to be in the form:

```
-(IBAction) epic:(id)sender {
```

Once you have done that you should probably delete and remake the link with your storyboard as that is likely to be broken too.

Comment: Thanks. It actually cleared up the error at  (void).  But now it keeps trying to tell me to put a ';' there which then creates another set of errors in the program

Comment: Why the commented lines (@end and @ implementation)?

Comment: @reivax7 yes - as Larme says that is because it thinks this is in the interface - uncomment those two @  lines and it will recognise that it is in the implementation and stop asking for a ;